# Is there a regex for adding the first 4 characters to end of string and the last 4 characters to start of string?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have some lines which I need to alter. They are protein sequences. How would I copy the first 4 characters of the line to the end of the line, and also copy the last 4 characters to the beginning of the line?
The strings are variable which complicates it, for example:

> >X
>
> LTGLGIGTGMAATIINAISVGLSAATILSLISGVASGGAWVLAGAKQALKEGGKKAGIAF
>
> >Y
>
> LVATGMAAGVAKTIVNAVSAGMDIATALSLFSGAFTAAGGIMALIKKYAQKKLWKQLIAA

Moreover, how could I exclude lines with a '>' at the beginning (these are names of the corresponding sequence)?

Does anyone know a regex which will allow this to work?

I've already tried some regex solutions but I'm not very experienced with this sort of thing and I can find the end string but can't get it to replace:

Find:

> (...)$

Replace:

> ^$2$1"

An example of what I want to achieve is:

> >1
>
> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

becomes:

> >1
>
> **WXYZ**ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ**ABCD**

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the regex below.

```
^(([A-Z]{4})([A-Z]*)([A-Z]{4}))$

^ asserts the position at the start of the line, so nothing can come before it.
( is the start of a capture group, this is group 1.
( is the start of a capture group, this is group 2. This group is inside group 1.
[A-Z]{4} means exactly 4 capital characters from A to Z.
) is the end of capture group 2.
( is the start of a capture group, this is group 3.
[A-Z]* matches capital characters from A to Z between zero and infinite times.
) is the end of capture group 3.
( is the start of a capture group, this is group 4.
[A-Z]{4} means exactly 4 capital characters from A to Z.
) is the end of capture group 4.
$ asserts the position at the end of the line, so nothing can come after it.
```

See how it works with a replace here: https://regex101.com/r/W786uL/3.

```
$4$1$2

$4 means put capture group 4 here. Which is the last 4 characters.
$1 means put capture group 1 here. Which is everything in the entire string.
$2 means put capture group 2 here. Which is the first 4 characters.
```

Answer (score 4):

Try doing a find, in regex mode, on the following pattern:

```
^([A-Z]{4}).*([A-Z]{4})$
```

Then replace with the first four and last four characters swapped:

```
$2$0$1
```

### Demo

Comment: Also, since NP++ uses perl-compatible regexes, you can shorten it a bit more: `^(\w{4})(\w+)(\w{4})$`

Comment: @Trix But in this case, I would rather limit to capital letters, as the OP's protein sequences would probably only contain them and not other word characters.

Comment: This is close, but I think you missed that OP wants to *copy* the character blocks, not simply swap them. The example should be replaced with `WXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCD`, as stated in the question. Your solution moves the blocks but doesn't copy them, giving `WXYZEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVABCD`.

Comment: @EdCottrell I only needed to change the replacement to `$3$0$1`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yep. I didn't want to change the substance of your post for you, but I figured you'd make the switch when you saw it. Nice, clean answer. Have a +1.

Comment: Didn't know about $0, also +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^(.{4})(.*?)(.{4})$
```

- `^` - start of sting
- `(.{4})` - Match any for characters except new line
- `(.*?)` - Match any character zero or more time (lazy mode)
- `$` - End of string

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/PrtDgr/1/)

Comment: You don't need to make the dot lazy in this case.

Comment: The data is only word-characters, and the questioner specifically asks to not match lines starting with a `>`